# Nested lists wih equal height independently of number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown multicolumn menu with nested lists and I need all three lists (or columns) to be the same height even if they have a different number of items. The lists are dynamic - the number of items can vary in each list. Is it possible or do I need to rewrite the HTML code? In the image you can see what I am trying to achieve:

[image: 1]

```js
const firstlevel = document.querySelectorAll(".first-level > li");
const secondlevel = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level > li");

const menuButton = document.querySelector(".menu-button")

menuButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  menuButton.classList.add('active');
});

firstlevel.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    firstlevel.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });

    item.classList.add("active");

    item.querySelector('ul > li').classList.add("active");

  });
});

secondlevel.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    secondlevel.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0abf53;
}

.dropdown li {}

.dropdown li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown li ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown li ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown li ul li ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul li:hover>a {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

ul li.active>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="menu-button"><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="first-level">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="second-level">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">1-1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">1-2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-2-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-2-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">1-3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul class="second-level">
          <li><a href="#">2-1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2-2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2-3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my try until now:
https://codepen.io/Agrimensor/pen/vYgGJwr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to pass a variable from JS to CSS and calculate height there.

```
const listLength = () => {
  let container = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
  let items = 0;
  let lists = container.querySelectorAll(".class-name-to-select-ul")
  list.forEach(x => {
    let liCount = x.querySelectorAll("li").lenght;
    items = items > liCount ? items : liCount;
  });
  container.setAttribute('style', `--items:${items}`)
}
```

```
ul {
  height: calc(var(--items) * var(--item-height))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed height to `.dropdown ul` , Like this:

```
.dropdown ul {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```js
const firstlevel = document.querySelectorAll(".first-level > li");
const secondlevel = document.querySelectorAll(".second-level > li");

const menuButton = document.querySelector(".menu-button")

menuButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  menuButton.classList.add('active');
});

firstlevel.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    firstlevel.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });

    item.classList.add("active");

    item.querySelector('ul > li').classList.add("active");

  });
});

secondlevel.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    secondlevel.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0abf53;
}

.dropdown li {}

.dropdown li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown li ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown li ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown li ul li ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul li:hover>a {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

ul li.active>ul {
  display: block;
}


/* NEW */

.dropdown ul {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="menu-button"><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="first-level">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="second-level">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">1-1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">1-2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-2-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-2-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">1-3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1-3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1-3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul class="second-level">
          <li><a href="#">2-1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2-2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2-3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">2-3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">2-3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> [Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/GRrZVgE)

Comment: Thank you, @Manas Khandelwal.I forgot to mention that lists are dynamic - the number of items can vary each time in each list. So all the lists need to be as long as the longest.